# How can I mock out responses made by aiohttp.ClientSession?

Tags: python-asyncio, aiohttp, pytest-aiohttp

I am using aiohttp to make asynchronous requests and I want to test my code. I want to mock out requests sent by aiohttp.ClientSession. I am looking for something similar to the way [responses](https://github.com/getsentry/responses) handles mocking for the `requests` lib.

How can I mock out responses made by `aiohttp.ClientSession`?

```
# sample method
async def get_resource(self, session):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        response = await self.session.get("some-external-api.com/resource")
        if response.status == 200:
            result = await response.json()
            return result

        return {...}

# I want to do something like ...
aiohttp_responses.add(
    method='GET', 
    url="some-external-api.com/resource", 
    status=200, 
    json={"message": "this worked"}
)

async def test_get_resource(self):
    result = await get_resource()
    assert result == {"message": "this worked"}
```

- I have read through the [aiohttp testing docs](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/testing.html). It seems they cover mocking out incoming requests to your web server, but I'm not sure this helps me mock out responses to outgoing requests

---

**Edit**

I've used https://github.com/pnuckowski/aioresponses on a few projects and it has worked well for my needs.

Comment: Maybe consider making your edit an answer? I would've upvoted it

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Since I posted this question, I have used this library for mocking out aiohttp requests: https://github.com/pnuckowski/aioresponses and it has worked well for my needs.

Comment: Fixed link: https://github.com/pnuckowski/aioresponses

Comment: Warning: as of 2022, it does not support matching on request body or headers, only URL and method.

Answer (score 30):

1. create mockresponse

```
class MockResponse:
    def __init__(self, text, status):
        self._text = text
        self.status = status

    async def text(self):
        return self._text

    async def __aexit__(self, exc_type, exc, tb):
        pass

    async def __aenter__(self):
        return self
```

2. use pytest mocker mock the request

```
@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_exchange_access_token(self, mocker):
    data = {}

    resp = MockResponse(json.dumps(data), 200)

    mocker.patch('aiohttp.ClientSession.post', return_value=resp)

    resp_dict = await account_api.exchange_access_token('111')
```

Comment: pip install pytest-mock

Comment: Nice but I can't transpose it to `ClientSession.request`. I tried several paths but without much success `aiohttp.ClientSession.request`, `aiohttp.client.ClientSession.request`, `aiohttp.client.ClientSession._request`

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a function which will return your mocked response:

```
async def create_resp(status_code=200, resp_data=None):
    resp = mock.AsyncMock(status_code=status_code)
    resp.json.return_value = resp_data
    return resp
```

2. Then use it in your test:

```
@pytest.mark.asyncio
@mock.patch('ms_printers.clients.menu.aiohttp.ClientSession.get')
async def test_ok(self, mock_get):
    mock_get.return_value = create_resp(resp_data={'a': 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use aioresponse, pytest and pytest-asyncio library.

```
    from aioresponses import aioresponse
    Import pytest

    # mock object here
    @pytest_asyncio.fixture
    async def mock_response():
        with aioresponses() as mocker:
            yield mocker

    # your client async here
    @pytest_asyncio.fixture
    @async def async_client():
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession as session:
            yield session
```

Then apply the mock response method

```
    @pytest.mark.fixture
    async def my_mock_client(async_client, mock_response):
        url = ("https://get-items.com/")
        response = {"key":"value"}
        mock_response.get(url, status=200, payload=response)
        response = await async_client.request("GET", url, **kwargs)
        assert response is not None
```

Also, aioresponse has no json parameter unlike responses.

You can use the `.add` in responses, but not in aioresponses.

I hope this helps.